# GPS reboots the phone

Tags: gps, overheating

When I use a GPS-intensive app (like Sport tracker or endomondo), if I turn off the screen, the phone reboots within one or two minutes.

What is the problem? What can I do?

How can I check the temperature to know if it's overheating? What can I do in this case?

(My phone is a Nexus One on Videotron (Canada))

Comment: You should also mention which is your device and os version :)

Comment: the phone might be overheated?

Answer (score 1):

Overheating.

You may have used it intensely and when you lock the screen you then put it in ur pocket?

Your phone will be overheating and restarting itself to stop damge to the circuits/processor.

Similar user issue [here](http://gdgt.com/discuss/i-am-having-a-problem-with-my-nexus-one-it-restarts-due-to-overheating-i-think-it-may-be-the-battery-any-experience-ideas-cm3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the battery temperature with "**[System Info widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.indepico.sysinfo&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5pbmRlcGljby5zeXNpbmZvIl0.)**"